# Error while implementing UISearchController for PFobjects

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, swift2

```
      import UIKit

    class MasterTableViewController: UITableViewController, PFLogInViewControllerDelegate, PFSignUpViewControllerDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating {


var searchNotes: PFObject = PFObject()
var filteredNotes =  [String]()

var resultSearchController = UISearchController()
var searchActive: Bool = false



 // creating array for holding ojects 



var noteObjects: NSMutableArray! = NSMutableArray()
  var v = 0




override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.resultSearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    self.resultSearchController.searchResultsUpdater = self

    self.resultSearchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    self.resultSearchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()

    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.resultSearchController.searchBar

    self.tableView.reloadData()





       }

   override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)



    if v == 0 {
        self.fetchAllObjectsFromLocalDataStore()
        //self.fetchAllObjects()

    }
   }


  // fetching data from local datastore and from parse

  func fetchAllObjectsFromLocalDataStore(){

    let query: PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Sinhgad")
    query.orderByDescending("createdAt")


    query.fromLocalDatastore()

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { ( objects, error) -> Void in

        if (error == nil) {




            let temp: NSArray = objects as NSArray!

            self.noteObjects = temp.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableArray

             self.tableView.reloadData()

        }else {
        print(error!.userInfo)

        }
    }

    }



   func fetchAllObjects(){

   let query: PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Sinhgad")
    query.orderByDescending("createdAt")


    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in

        if (error == nil) {

          PFObject.pinAllInBackground(objects, block:  nil )


            self.fetchAllObjectsFromLocalDataStore()

           // self.tableView.reloadData()

        } else {
        print(error?.userInfo)

        }
    }
  }

   override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
   }



  // MARK: - Table view data source

  override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
  }

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    if self.resultSearchController.active
    {
        return self.filteredNotes.count
    }else{

    return self.noteObjects.count
    }}


   override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MasterTableViewCell


    if self.resultSearchController.active
    {
        cell.textLabel?.text = self.filteredNotes[indexPath.row]





        searchNotes  = self.noteObjects.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! PFObject
        cell.MasterTitleLabel?.text = searchNotes["Title"] as? String

        cell.MasterTextLabel.text = searchNotes["Fstory"] as? String
        cell.MasterTimeLabel.text = searchNotes["Time"] as? String
        cell.MasterLocationLabel.text =  searchNotes["Location"] as? String


  return cell

    } else {
 let object : PFObject = self.noteObjects.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! PFObject



    cell.MasterTitleLabel?.text = object["Title"] as? String
    cell.MasterTextLabel.text = object["Fstory"] as? String
    cell.MasterTimeLabel.text = object["Time"] as? String
    cell.MasterLocationLabel.text = object["Location"] as? String

    print(searchNotes)

return cell
    }}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if self.resultSearchController.active
    {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("openStory", sender: self)

    } else {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("openStory", sender: self)
}

}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    let upcoming: AddNoteTableViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! AddNoteTableViewController

    if (segue.identifier == "openStory"){




        let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!

   let object: PFObject = self.noteObjects.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! PFObject



        upcoming.object = object

        self.tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
}

}


@IBAction func btnReload(sender: AnyObject) {

    fetchAllObjects()
    print(searchNotes)
 }


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete ){

        if self.resultSearchController.active
        {


        }else{



        let object : PFObject = self.noteObjects.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! PFObject
        // the below for deleting the selected cell's object from server's database
       // object.deleteInBackground()

        //the below for deleting the selected cell's object from localstorage
        object.unpinInBackground()


      self.noteObjects.removeObjectAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        }
      tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)

  }
}    
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {

    self.filteredNotes.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

    let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text!)

    let array = (self.noteObjects as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)

    self.filteredNotes = array as! [String]
    self.tableView.reloadData()



    print(searchNotes)



}
}
```

i am trying  to implement uisearchbar but i don't know whats wrong when am trying to run the app getting an error if somebody knows whats wrong than please tell me

the error am getting :

```
2015-12-04 00:41:31.915 Notes[1950:228026] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Can only call -[PFObject init] on subclasses conforming to PFSubclassing.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106ff8e65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000108d37deb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106ff8d9d +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
    3   Notes                               0x00000001059abac6 -[PFObject init] + 146
    4   Notes                               0x000000010597c5b0 _TTOFCSo8PFObjectcfMS_FT_S_ + 16
    5   Notes                               0x000000010597c2e7 _TFCSo8PFObjectCfMS_FT_S_ + 71
    6   Notes                               0x000000010597b2a5 _TFC5Notes25MasterTableViewControllercfMS0_FT5coderCSo7NSCoder_GSqS0__ + 37
    7   Notes                               0x000000010597b3fd _TToFC5Notes25MasterTableViewControllercfMS0_FT5coderCSo7NSCoder_GSqS0__ + 45
    8   UIKit                               0x0000000107bd417f -[UIClassSwapper initWithCoder:] + 241
    9   UIKit                               0x0000000107da67ba UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 705
    10  UIKit                               0x0000000107da64f0 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 278
    11  UIKit                               0x0000000107bd3e55 -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:] + 180
    12  UIKit                               0x0000000107bd4589 -[UIRuntimeEventConnection initWithCoder:] + 60
    13  UIKit                               0x0000000107da67ba UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 705
    14  UIKit                               0x0000000107da697b UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 1154
    15  UIKit                               0x0000000107da64f0 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 278
    16  UIKit                               0x0000000107bd3067 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1255
    17  UIKit                               0x0000000107f39a04 -[UIStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:] + 181
    18  UIKit                               0x0000000107f3e6c8 -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate instantiateOrFindDestinationViewControllerWithSender:] + 90
    19  UIKit                               0x0000000107f3e925 -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _perform:] + 52
    20  UIKit                               0x0000000107f3ec07 -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate perform:] + 156
    21  UIKit                               0x00000001078198c8 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 92
    22  UIKit                               0x0000000107988328 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    23  UIKit                               0x00000001079885f4 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 311
    24  UIKit                               0x0000000107987724 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 601
    25  UIKit                               0x0000000107888bcf -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 835
    26  UIKit                               0x0000000107889904 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 865
    27  UIKit                               0x000000010783829a -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 263
    28  UIKit                               0x0000000117611ff9 -[UIApplicationAccessibility sendEvent:] + 77
    29  UIKit                               0x00000001078124cb _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 6844
    30  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106f24a31 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    31  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106f1a8d7 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 423
    32  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106f19e13 __CFRunLoopRun + 867
    33  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106f19828 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    34  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010ab6aad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
    35  UIKit                               0x0000000107817d44 UIApplicationMain + 171
    36  Notes                               0x0000000105971afd main + 109
    37  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000109ebd92d start + 1
    38  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

i am trying  to implement uisearchbar but i don't know whats wrong when am trying to run the app getting an error if somebody knows whats wrong than please tell me

Answer (score 0):

This error caused by line `var searchNotes: PFObject = PFObject()` and it means that you cannot instantiate object directly. According to [Developers Guide](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide) you need to instantiate your object using its actual name from Parse Cloud. Something like this:

```
var searchNotes = PFObject(className:"YourObjectName")
```

Update.

Reading your code I assume that you want to use array of `PFObject`'s instead of single object.

Update.

I bet you next error is cause by this two lines:

```
let array = (self.noteObjects as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
self.filteredNotes = array as! [String]
```

because you try to use predicate for `String` with `PFObjects`. But this question is not related with original.

Ok. I guess you need this:

```
let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text!)
var array = (self.noteObjects as! [PFObject]).map { (obj) -> String 
  obj["Title"]
}
array = (array as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
```

Comment: tried as you suggested but now view is showing but when am trying to enter something in my search bar its showing error

Comment: 2015-12-04 01:31:22.829 Notes[2212:253640] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't use in/contains operator with collection <Sinhgad: 0x7fb1a9fb67e0, objectId: G9YhlunbIe, localId: (null)> {
    Fstory = "Trial ";
    Location = cali;
    Time = "9:00";
    Title = "December ";
} (not a collection)'

Comment: class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate { signal SIGABART

Comment: what if i want to search the data which is stored in local storage ??

Comment: its showing error expected declaration  in this line { (obj) -> String  (consecutive statements )

Comment: now am getting error in next line :      array = (array as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)

Comment: 'cannot assign value of type [anyobject]  to type [string] '

Comment: hey i tried as! [String] now no errors but when am opening the app and tapping the serchbar everything is disappearing tableview is there but not its contents @rkyr

Comment: hey thanks its working now but kinda weird type but its working thanks